# Lambda function help – showing data based on multi-cell search in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with one tab for each month. Within each month, I can select a number (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) and add a text note for each day.

The numbers and text notes from all days in all tabs show up on the "Entries" page.

Issue:
If I have added a text note for a given day, but haven't given it a number, the text note shows in the wrong row in the entries tab. You can see it here: https://www.loom.com/share/5802a113dc184115b75cd085d7325384?sid=cea8938c-4df5-448a-9279-977f986ccb43

And here's the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dUEKXSCCohBIV_hg6k6c8mwXEXcQEQ6ADBcwBKMb1LE/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me update my lambda function?

I have more questions about this file, but will limit the scope here to a single question.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dUEKXSCCohBIV_hg6k6c8mwXEXcQEQ6ADBcwBKMb1LE/edit#gid=1936028622) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,indirect(A1&"!B4:AC26"),
     Λ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(6,1,1,4),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,
       reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(7,1,1,4),lambda(x,y,vstack(x,hstack(index(Σ,c,y),index(Σ,c,y+3),index(Σ,c+1,y),index(Σ,c+2,y)))))))),
     map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,ifna(index(vlookup(Σ,Λ,{2,3,4},))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for your effort!