# Lambda function help – matching day number and value associated with it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with one tab for each month. Within each month, I can select a number (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) for each day.

1. I'd like the number assigned to each day in the monthly view to appear in the corresponding row on the summary view "Annual Report".

Issue: that the number is showing in the next row, rather than the row that it corresponds to. See explanation: https://www.loom.com/share/43e7ab789f534dc6b2f5ddc44de0c8b4?sid=f922295f-8a94-4f63-8694-da6c7ae08cef

2. I'd like to calculate a summary (mean, mode) of scores by day of week. I'm unsure how to do this. Explanation here: https://www.loom.com/share/2cc69983ce10466183278a93bd54bd6d?sid=5d5a8301-f854-4b25-ad5d-53c7da120110

Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dUEKXSCCohBIV_hg6k6c8mwXEXcQEQ6ADBcwBKMb1LE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your interest and help.

Answer (score 1):

*Possible solution added to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dUEKXSCCohBIV_hg6k6c8mwXEXcQEQ6ADBcwBKMb1LE/edit#gid=941557844):*

```js
=map($A5:$A,lambda(Σ,let(Λ,xmatch(M3,Sol!$A1:$BH1),xlookup(Σ,index(day(choosecols(Sol!$A:$BH,Λ))),choosecols(Sol!$A:$BH,Λ+1),))))
```

[image]

*For the mean/mode metrics an improvised formula from [previous offered solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76864063/5479575) is used in `Cell_Z1` to pull data from all the 12 months into one file and then [average](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529) `column_W` & [mode](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094029) `column_X` are calculated*

```js
=let(data,reduce(tocol(,1),B3:M3,lambda(Λ,Σ,vstack(Λ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(6,1,1,4),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(7,1,1,4),lambda(x,y,vstack(x,hstack(index(indirect(Σ&"!B4:AC26"),c,y),index(indirect(Σ&"!B4:AC26"),c,y+3))))))))))),filter(data,index(data,,2)<>""))
```

*average*: `=iferror(round(averageif(index(if(len(Z:Z),text(Z:Z,"dddd"),)),V5,AA:AA),2))`

*mode*: `=ifna(mode(filter(AA:AA,if(len(Z:Z),text(Z:Z,"dddd"),)=V5)))`